# States list drop down is giving first value even after selecting any value from the list upon form submission

Tags: php

Below is my complete code to populate states list based on selected country. When I select any country from country drop down, it returns proper states list in states drop down. This part is working fine.

When I select country USA, states drop down is filled with states of USA and default selected state is `Alska`. Now if I change state value from `Alaska` to 'Texas' and submits form, it just sends value 0 to submit page.

I think this 0 value is coming from `<option value="0">-- Select State --</option>` in `id=before_get_state`. So how can I resolve this issue? Please help.

**Country Drop Down**

`GetRecordSet` is used to fetch records from MySQL database

`CheckSelected` is used to display specific value as default selected value in dropdown

```
<form name="frm_shipping_address" id="frm_shipping_address" novalidate>
<div class="control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label>Select Country</label><span class="text-help-form"> * </span>
            <?php 
            $str_query_select="";
            $str_query_select="SELECT * FROM " .$STR_DB_TABLE_NAME_COUNTRY. " WHERE visible='YES' ORDER BY title ASC";
            $rs_list_country=GetRecordSet($str_query_select);
            ?>
            <select name="cbo_country" id="cbo_country" class="form-control" onChange="get_state(this.value);" required="" data-validation-required-message="Select Country" >
            <option value="0">-- Select Country --</option>
            <?php
            while(!$rs_list_country->EOF()==true) { ?>
                <option value="<?php print($rs_list_country->fields("pkid"))?>" <?php print(CheckSelected($rs_list_country->fields("pkid"),$int_user_countrypkid)); ?>><?php print($rs_list_country->fields("title")); ?></option>
            <?php $rs_list_country->MoveNext(); } ?>
            </select>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="btn_continue" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><b>SUBMIT&nbsp;</b></button>
</form>
```

**State Drop Down**

```
<div class="control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label>Select State</label><span class="text-help-form"> * </span>
        <div id="before_get_state">
            <select name="cbo_state" id="cbo_state" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">-- Select State --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="after_get_state"></div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery / AJAX**

`jquery.min.js`, `jqBootstrapValidation.js` files are included in the page

```
<script>
function get_state(countrypkid) {
    var int_countrypkid = countrypkid;
    var dataString = "countrypkid="+int_countrypkid;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./product_address_get_state_p.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#before_get_state").hide();
            $("#after_get_state").html(html);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**product_address_get_state_p.php Page Code**

```
$int_statepkid = 0;
if(isset($_SESSION['userpkid']) && $_SESSION['userpkid'] != "")
{
    $str_query_select = "SELECT statepkid FROM t_user WHERE pkid=".$_SESSION['userpkid'];
    $rs_list_user = GetRecordSet($str_query_select);
    $int_statepkid = $rs_list_user->fields("statepkid");
}

$int_countrypkid = 0;
if(isset($_POST["countrypkid"]))
{
    $int_countrypkid = trim($_POST["countrypkid"]);
}

$str_query_select = "SELECT * FROM " .$STR_DB_TABLE_NAME_STATE. " WHERE masterpkid=".$int_countrypkid." AND visible='YES' ORDER BY title ASC";
$rs_list_state = GetRecordSet($str_query_select);

echo "<select class='form-control' name='cbo_state' id='cbo_state'>";
while(!$rs_list_state->EOF()==true)
{ 
    echo "<option value='" .$rs_list_state->fields('pkid'). "' ".CheckSelected($rs_list_state->fields('pkid'),$int_statepkid).">".$rs_list_state->fields('title')."</option>";
    $rs_list_state->MoveNext();
} 
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: I would just do `$("#before_get_state").html(html);` and remove `$("#after_get_state").html(html);` and `<div id="after_get_state"></div>`. Then inspect element on the `select` after you set the country and see what the values of the states are.

Comment: I should also note you should not put values submitted by the user right into the sql query. You are open to SQL injections. Look into binding parameters/values.